# TeXStudio move embedded preview window (stacked mode)

Tags: texstudio

I prefer to have my TeX code and my preview window stacked, rather than side-by-side.

At the moment I achieve this by using windowed mode, then simply arranging the windows. (As per the comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416151/31839))

But this has the unpleasant side-effect of switching focus to the preview every time I run a build. Since I almost never want this, I have to switch back to the code window after every build.

Is there a way to:

a) keep the preview window embedded, or
b) stop focus switching to the preview on build when in windowed preview mode?

**TeXstudio 2.10.8**
**Ubuntu 14.0.4**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Settings -> Build -> PDF viewer`, pass the options:

- `--no-focus`: preventing the window focus from shifting to the PDF viewer when `txs:///view-pdf` is called, (e.g., after compilation, using <kbd>F7</kbd> etc.).
- `--no-foreground`: preventing the PDF viewer window from coming into the foreground.

The `--no-foreground` is only required because you're using the `Stacked` view option.

So for example, it might look like this:

> PDF Viewer: `txs:///view-pdf-internal --windowed --no-focus --no-foreground`

[image: txs pdf viewer]

Comment: You just made my computer mouse very unhappy because it is hardly gonna be used now :)

Comment: @samcarter On the other hand, your keyboard's gonna be really happy :)

Comment: Of course it is - it has all the keys to type :) and :D

Comment: Perfect! Just a detail: you need to have "Advanced Options" visible to do this...